# Antonym for "Dense"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I feel like there is no perfect word to describe the opposite of "dense." Density as in mass divided by volume.

All I can think of are words like "light," "fluffy," or "sparse" that aren't exactly what I am trying to say when describing something that has a large volume, but not a lot of mass.

> Of all the bowling balls he preferred the [not dense] ones because throwing them down the alley fast made him feel cool.

Comment: Sometimes the opposite of a word is 'not + word'. If Light and fluffy didn't work, I would probably just use 'not dense'.

Comment: It's totally context dependent.   "Light" will work in the context of baking, while "diffuse" will work in the context of gasses, for example.  Wat is your context?

Comment: Please write an example sentence where the word would be used. I am voting to put this question on hold as there is neither context nor example sentence.

Comment: "Attenuated" might be a (context-free) antonym.

Comment: An unnecessary example sentence has been added. The context is the physical attribute of a substance.

Comment: @tkendrick20 *"he preferred the **lighter** ones"*

Comment: @NVZ The example sentence isn't my best work, but I am trying to say "lighter" while also alluding to the fact that the other options are all the same size, too.

Comment: *Vacuous* could work in the physical sense for some specific situations.  Just not this one.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm gathering that there is no universal antonym for the word "dense" and the word choice is entirely dependent on the context.

Comment: Itl’s a given that bowling balls are all the same size, so as @NVZ says, ***lighter*** is ***the*** word.  Note that bowling balls are measured by weight:  In the US: typically 8-16 lbs.

Comment: @tkendrick20: Only a geek would categorize bowling balls by *density*, and even then the descriptor for a ***lighter*** ball would just be ***less dense*** anyway. Your specific context is thus not very appropriate, but for the more general case ***diffuse*** is probably the most relevant term. There will be context-specific alternatives, but in comparisons like *Aluminium is **X** than lead* (where both alternatives are *solid*) you should probably always just switch from density to weight.

Comment: The most suitable one should be SPARSE I guess. Why it wouldn't suit  your description?

Comment: @TurkanAlisoy **Sparse** would be suitable if you were talking about the number of balls per room, perhaps.

Comment: If you want to refer specifically to the ball's density, you would probably have to say "he preferred the lower-density ones".

Comment: @tkendrick20 Is your example the *only* context in which you want to use the word; or are you wanting this for broader use as well? If you want a general word you may want to add that to the question. I feel the whole 'bowling ball' thing is muddying the waters.

Comment: This question makes no sense; you wouldn't call ANY bowling ball "not dense". All of them are dense. Some are just *less dense*. And there's no word for *less dense* because there doesn't *need* to be a word for *less dense*.

Comment: @V0ight, that was an _example_. The question was posed out of _curiosity_ after speaking with a scientist friend. There are plenty of words that don't _need_ to exist.

Comment: You're right, @Skooba, but people were threatening to close the question if it did not contain an example (which I believed to be unnecessary because I wanted a general word).

Comment: The example sentence establishes context not available in the question, which is why it is mandatory. I think you're too closely equating the physical "density" with the common use of "dense". Consider height. Tall refers to a relatively large measurement of height, short the opposite. Likewise, density is used in the technical sense like height, and dense is used in the common language like tall. So dense things have a lot of density. There is no universal corresponding term for density analogous to short, or "things without a lot of density". In context, various work-arounds can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A historical word to mean the opposite of dense was **rare**, as stated in the following taken from an article in [DON'T LOOK NOW
IT'S DEVAN GOLDSTEIN](https://devangoldstein.com/2009/07/22/opposite-of-dense/):

> Once upon a time, though, dense had an opposite. Until the mid-19th century, the word was rare.
>
> In fact, the earliest meaning of rare in English was precisely this one. The OED notes the word’s meaning as “[o]pposed to dense,” and provides the following example (from around 1420), among others: The londis fatte, or lene, or thicke, or rare.

---

Also, a check of current dictionary definitions gives us [this one](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rare) from Merriam-Webster:

> **rare:** marked by wide separation of component particles; thin (e.g. rare air)

So, rare does seem to be used for "objects of low(er) density" in the physics sense of the word. This is because typically when we think of "dense" we think of "heavy", but in the pure physical world this in not the case as weight is subjective, while (as you mentioned) mass and volume are not.

Now the caveat to all this, is that the usage of word this way in now *rare* itself (pun intended). It quite possible that you will get a odd look or be misunderstood if you ask for a "rare bowling ball".

Comment: I didn't downvote, because of course this is a valid, useful answer explaining that the word *rare* is archaic in this sense.   But people tend to view voting as a popularity contest in which the standings need adjustment.   The downvotes are likely no more than people trying to make *lighter* appear more valid.  All the more so because your answer got the checkmark.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I offered an alternative answer instead. But those who did downvote may not have agreed that "rare" is an appropriate description of a lighter bowling ball, or they may have felt that an archaic use of the word is not a useful *contemporary* antonym for "dense". But in the end it's a poorly worded question, which is why it's been put on hold - we may both have wasted our time!

Answer (score 4):

> *"Of all the bowling balls, he preferred the **lighter** ones because throwing them down the alley fast made him feel cool."*

**Light** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/light)

> *adj.* 1.a. having little weight; not heavy

Comment: I'm assuming all the balls available there are of same size.

Comment: They have to be 1. Because of regulations and fairness. 2. because the ball handling/return system requires it.

Answer (score 3):

Bowling ball terminology says POROSITY

http://www.bowlingthismonth.com/bowling-balls/

And throw a ball is most likely a NO NO. I believe the term is to HOOK a ball....

You might want to look into dynamic in this text, too:
https://bowler2bowler.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/bowling-ball-terminology-maintenance-by-james-goulding-iii/

Comment: This one is close, but other substances that are not dense can also be nonporous.

Comment: It's not about all substances, though, is it? It's about a bowling ball. Heavy substance, light substance; dense substance, porous substance. Hook that down the lane....

Answer (score 3):

This question asks for a word "describing something that has a large volume, but not a lot of mass" - yet gives an example of two small dense objects (bowling balls) with relatively modest variation in weight. This might be making it harder to see what an appropriate antonym of "dense" might be. Some different examples might be useful…

> Compare the air at sea level with the air at the top of Everest: the latter, being less dense, is **rarified**.
>
> Compare a party balloon filled with water and a party balloon filled with helium: water is denser than helium, so the helium balloon is **light**.

Note that density (mass per unit volume) is not the same as *weight* or *heaviness*: in an inertial environment (e.g. Space Station), both granite and pumice are weightless, so the term "light" is really just our layperson's way of comparing the *mass* of different objects.

> Compare a piece of granite with a piece of pumice: apart from being "light", the latter is **porous**.
>
> Compare the Moon with a [white dwarf star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf) (both are about the same size, but the white dwarf has roughly the same mass as the Sun): the Moon is **less massive**.

Answer (score -3):

Other than 'sparse', I would suggest:

- [dispersed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispersed): spread apart, distributed or spread over a wide area,
- [scarce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scarce): very small in amount or number, not plentiful,

Comment: While these words may be antonyms of *dense* in some senses, they are not antonyms of *dense* in the sense given by the asker.